# How would I reflect the possible changes to the journey that could follow a decision?

Tags: gui-design, mobile, mobile-application

[image]

I'm currently working on the UI wireframing for a taxi booking and sharing app.

When a user requests a seat in a taxi you've booked, then you receive a notification.

Prior to making a decision of accepting or rejecting a request, you get to see the implications that it has on your existing journey. Now I am having difficulty showing this in the app. In the instance above, I've simply highlighted the changes in a different colour. The things that change include your journey details change, price, journey time and distance. Secondly if you had 4 seats available in your taxi, it gets reduced to 3.

Would there be a better way of showing a before/after snapshot (i.e. what the journey looks like now and what it would look like afterwards)?

I was advised to use stock tickers, and a combination of color and icons to represent the change, but how would this look like with my current interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to accent changes more precisely, as they are decision points, and display the old data, as decision could be based on comparison.
[image]

To focus user on changing lines, you could visualize it with side marks. It's like tracking changes in code editors:
[image]